# CakePHP: Can't pass the parameters of a belongsTo object from a form

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I have two classes now, Jobs and Users. There is an association in the Jobs, that "Many Job belongs to a User". Everything is working fine, until I don't want to filter (search) for the User's name on the Job's page. I'm doing this with the CakePHP's Search Plugin.

In the Job's View:

```
echo $this->Form->input('User.name', array('type' => 'text', 'div' => false));
echo $this->Form->input('status', array('type' => 'select', 'div' => false));
...
```

In the Job's Model:

```
public $filterArgs = array(
    'User.name' => array('type' => 'like'),
    'status' => array('type' => 'like'),
    ...
);
```

My problem is basically, that when I submit my filter/search, it does not forward the User.name parameter in the GET list (in the params array), but if I manually extend my URL with "User.name:something", then it works fine. So after submission my URL looks like:

```
localhost/jobs/index/status:/release_filter:/system_codes_filter:/subsystem_codes_filter:
```

instead of:

```
localhost/jobs/index/User.name:something/status:/release_filter:/system_codes_filter:/subsystem_codes_filter:
```

And as I mentioned, if I put this link (with the manually inserted User.name:something part) in the browser, it works fine.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meanwhile I could get it working. It was really just few characters.. I copy the result, maybe someone can use it later.

Model:

```
public $filterArgs = array(
  'username' => array('type' => 'like', 'field' => 'User.name'),
  'status' => array('type' => 'like'),
  ...
);
```

View:

```
echo $this->Form->input('username', array('type' => 'text', 'div' => false));
echo $this->Form->input('status', array('type' => 'select', 'div' => false));
...
```